# -(IBAction)goToWebSite:(id)sender not working

Tags: ios, user-interface

Just started my first project and I can't get it to work properly

It's a keyword search for my website.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *webSite = @"http://www.mydomain.eu/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webSite];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webPage loadRequest:request];

}

-(IBAction)goToWebSite:(id)sender {
    NSString *webSite = @""http://www.mydomain.eu/m/?keyword=,addressBar.text];  
    [webPage loadRequest:request];

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

The app loads so the first part is working but after it needs to fire the submit, by going to:

http://www.mydomain.eu/m/?keyword=,addressBar.text

It loads my website and after entering a keyword it should go to

http://www.mydomain.eu/m/?keyword=A_KEYWORD

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way. It may help

```
  -(IBAction)goToWebSite:(id)sender {
            NSString *webSite = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mydomain.eu/m/?keyword=%@",addressBar.text];  
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webSite];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [webPage loadRequest:request];

        }
```

Comment: @Execute Welcome. Upvote the answer. So others can get it fastly.